# Software level architecture of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I was going through this video: [Architecture of StackOverflow - Marco Cecconi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGi8FT2j8hE) where he says there are few projects in the Stack Overflow solution. And this made me curious.

What is the architecture of Stack Overflow Solution directory and since the video isn't clear about the projects inside the solution, can anyone tell me what they are? And how each project is dependent on the other.

**EDIT** This is not the same question as "what is stackoverflow built with". This question is specific to the software side of it, basically the Layered architecture of StackOverflow and the Visual Studio **Solution** directory.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is not the same question

Comment: Did you mention to Marco you're going to post this here?

Comment: I might need to ask his permissions first. Thanks @ShadowWizard

Comment: No problem, while you do post link here and if he agree he can reopen this and even post what he told you as an official answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you @ShadowWizard. I will wait for his reply.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely a different question.

Comment: @Sklivvz so you're posting this? I find it interesting too but it's quite on the border, being part of your source code and everything.

Comment: Downvoters, please mention why you are downvoting.

Comment: I have no idea (except that the title could be more specific and talk about your exact question.) Upvoted to offset

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe we should just give you the entire source stack on a USB stick so that you can study it. The other question makes it clear that it is an ASP.NET MVC architecture, and it's not all that difficult to guess the rest from the list of technologies, if you're willing to do a little work and read.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question was related to the video mentioned and the architecture Marco mentioned in that.. plus my own curiosity. Not the "Its MVC architecture, which means its got a bunch of models, some views and some controllers and they all interact with 5 layers of cache subsystem to generate page views, oh and then there is the webapi layer with a redis messaging system layer there."

Comment: *That* is the makings of a *real* question, not "how are the folders arranged."  Why do people always ask about that?  It is probably the *least* important detail in a system structure.

Comment: I'm guessing Marco has a specific answer in mind @RobertHarvey. So perhaps let's wait that one out. It's admittedly not the best/correct way, but maybe we can then transform the question itself into something a bit more reasonable?

Comment: Bart and I just gave you some sound guidance.  Why don't you consider it?  Make it a real question, not some hand-waving about folders.  We don't ask any less from people on Stack Overflow.

Comment: How can I make it more obvious that it was regards to the Video? @RobertHarvey

Comment: If that video is that important for the question, then please summarise (in text) what's in that external resource?

Comment: I posted a link to the video and asked a question specific to the video, yet being slightly more deeper, basically like if I would ask if I was sitting in the audience... and I don't know of any other better place than meta, or to ask Marco himself. Both which I did. @Arjan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are our projects, each one is a different product:

- Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/, this site and all the *.stackexchange.com sites)
- Stack Auth (http://stackauth.com/)
- Stack Overflow API
- Stack Overflow APIv2
- Stack Overflow Mobile (private API for mobile apps)
- Stack Server, the backbone server code for our Tag Server (among others)
- Socket Server, web sockets server
- A Unit Tests project
- A project for build files

Layering is done mostly using folders within each project. If we have common dependencies, they are productized and extracted to separate solutions using an internal nuget (or external if we open source it).

There are a few dependencies across projects, mostly to share code that is not productized.

Here's the dependency graph:

[image: digraph g{Build;SocketServer->StackOverflow;StackAuth->StackOverflow;StackAuth-"StackOverflow.Api.V2";"StackOverflow.Api"->StackOverflow;"StackOverflow.Api.V2"->StackOverflow;StackMobile->StackOverflow;StackMobile->"StackOverflow.Api.V2";"StackOverflow.Tests"->StackOverflow;StackServer->StackOverflow;}]

Comment: thanks for the mail as well as for the answer Marco. I might ask some more questions as I get into deeper knowledge of the architecture as and when needed, if its ok with you.. Thank you for your kindness!